# Will it cause resource leak that setting a stream object to null but not explicitly closing it?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, io, stream, destructor

```
FileReader f = new FileReader("foo.txt");
// Now there is a file descriptor (or file handle) created by OS.
f = null;
// Please note: we don't call f.close(), will the file handle
// be closed automatically?
```

Will it cause resource (file descriptor / file handle) leak in Java?

Comment: Try it and see. Not that it matters, you should always close resources.

Comment: I believe you should use the "try with resources" idiom.

Answer (score 2):

This is a Duplicate: [Do unclosed streams cause memory leaks in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889075/do-unclosed-streams-cause-memory-leaks-in-java)

The short answer is: not really. The stream will be finalized by the garbage collector. But you do not know when this will happen. So you waste some memory for some time.

Comment: What is more important, you waste an OS file descriptor. Number of file descriptors may be limited, and you can hit this limit pretty easily before garbage collector decided to wipe your object. Also the file might be locked on some operating systems until it's closed and you may have bad times trying to delete/rewrite it.