# Java FileInputStream out of memory issue

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to read an excel file and then write to csv file using xssf .I am getting out of memory error(Heap space). i see that fileinputstream is good for memory management ,but still i see the issue

```
package xlsxtocsv;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class xlsxtocsv
{

    private static final String NEW_LINE_CHARACTER="\r\n";

    /**
     * Write the string into a text file 
     * @param csvFileName
     * @param csvData
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static void writeCSV(String csvFileName,String csvData) throws Exception{
        FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(csvFileName);
        writer.write(csvData.getBytes());
        writer.close();
        System.out.println("Sucessfully written data to "+csvFileName);
    }


    public static void excelXToCSVfile(String excelFileName,String csvFileName,String Field_Delimiter,int Sheet_Number) {
         checkValidFile(excelFileName);
         XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook;
        try {
            myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(excelFileName));

            XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(Sheet_Number);
             String csvData="";
             DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter(Locale.US);
             checkValidFile(excelFileName);

             int rows = mySheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
             String prefix="\"";

             for (int eachRow = 0;eachRow<rows;eachRow++) {
                 XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) mySheet.getRow(eachRow);
                     for ( int i=0;i<myRow.getLastCellNum();i++){
                         if(i==0)
                         {

                             csvData += prefix+formatter.formatCellValue(myRow.getCell(i))+prefix;

                         }
                         else
                         {
                             csvData += Field_Delimiter+prefix+formatter.formatCellValue(myRow.getCell(i))+prefix;

                         }


                     }
                     csvData+=NEW_LINE_CHARACTER;
             }




                 try {
                    writeCSV(csvFileName, csvData);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



         }


    /**
     * get Cell value from XLSX file column
     * @param myCell
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */

        private static void checkValidFile(String fileName){
        boolean valid=true;
        try{
            File f = new File(fileName);
            if ( !f.exists() || f.isDirectory() ){
                valid=false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            valid=false;
        }
        if ( !valid){
            System.out.println("File doesn't exist: " + fileName);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String inp_file_name="";
        String Output_file_name="";
        String delimiter=",";


        //inp_file_name=args[0];    
        //Output_file_name=args[1]; 

    enter code here
        //delimiter=args[2];


        inp_file_name="C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/cloudera_shared/test_data.xlsx";
        Output_file_name="C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/cloudera_shared/test_data.csv";
        delimiter="|";



    if(args.length==4 && (args[3].equals("") == false))
    {

        int Sheet_Number=Integer.parseInt(args[3]); 
        excelXToCSVfile(inp_file_name,Output_file_name,delimiter,Sheet_Number);


    }
    else
    {

        excelXToCSVfile(inp_file_name,Output_file_name,delimiter,0);
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: suppose you close the `fileinputstream` in a finally block which is always safe. Refer this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889075/do-unclosed-streams-cause-memory-leaks-in-java) it may be helpful.

Comment: _"`fileinputstream` is good for memory management "_ - what gives you that idea? The two concepts are unrelated.  Also, why are you duplicating what Excel already does? Excel is quite capable of writing CSV from an xls file.

Comment: What is length of the CsvData when execute writeCSV method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the max size of the heap memory available to your Java process like this (here I increase it to 1024 MB).

```
java -Xmx1024m -jar myProgram.jar
```

If you run `java -X` you can see the different options available.

Try running your program in a profiler to get a better idea of which parts are memory intensive.

Comment: I tried even with 3000m ,no improvement it says out of memory at         FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(csvFileName);

Comment: How big is your excel file?

Comment: it is just 35 mb and my system has a ram of 16 gb

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the problems beyond your code:

1. `String csvData` should be replaced with `StringBuffer csvData`.
2. You can declare `FileOutputStream(nameFile, true)` (set append is true)
3. You can use the *multithread* to execute 2 tasks:

   - First: read content from your file excel.
   - Two: write that content which is has just read.